# NotSerializableException with redisson-spring-boot-starter

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, redis, redisson

I'm using redisson-spring-boot-starter 3.13.2 and Kotlin for cache but I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.service.message.State
    at org.redisson.RedissonObject.encodeMapValue(RedissonObject.java:338)
    at org.redisson.RedissonMapCache.fastPutOperationAsync(RedissonMapCache.java:843)
    at org.redisson.RedissonMapCache.fastPutAsync(RedissonMapCache.java:746)
    at org.redisson.RedissonMapCache.fastPut(RedissonMapCache.java:720)
    at org.redisson.spring.cache.RedissonCache.put(RedissonCache.java:107)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.AbstractCacheInvoker.doPut(AbstractCacheInvoker.java:87)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport$CachePutRequest.apply(CacheAspectSupport.java:820)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:429)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:345)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:747)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689)
    at ...
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.service.message.State
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:272)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractObjectOutput.writeObject(AbstractObjectOutput.java:58)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractMarshaller.writeObject(AbstractMarshaller.java:111)
    at org.redisson.codec.MarshallingCodec$4.encode(MarshallingCodec.java:176)
    at org.redisson.RedissonObject.encodeMapValue(RedissonObject.java:336)
    ... 115 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.jboss.marshalling.TraceInformation: null
```

This is how my config class looks like:

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
class CacheConfig {
    @Bean
    fun cacheManager(client: RedissonClient): CacheManager {
        val config = org.redisson.spring.cache.CacheConfig()
        config.ttl = 10 * 60 * 1000
        return RedissonSpringCacheManager(client, mapOf("State" to config))
    }
}
```

Type that I'm trying to cache:

```
data class State(
    val phoneCode: String,
    val phoneNumber: String
)
```

And this is how I'm trying to cache it:

```
@CachePut(value = ["State"], key = "#id")
    fun initializeState(phoneAreaCode: String, phoneNumber: String, id: String): State {
        ...
        return State(
            phoneCode = "...",
            phoneNumber = "...",
            ...
        )
    }
```

Edit: I managed to by pass this error by adding `JsonJacksonCodec()` to `RedissonSpringCacheManager(client, mapOf("State" to config), JsonJacksonCodec())` but now I'm having trouble deserializing:

```
unable to decode data. channel: [id: 0x81736df6, L:/...], reply: ReplayingDecoderByteBuf(ridx=1704, widx=1704), command: (EVAL), params: [local value = redis.call('hget', KEYS[1], ARGV[2]); if value == false then return nil; end; local t,..., 5, ...
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException: Missing type id when trying to resolve subtype of [simple type, class java.lang.Object]: missing type id property '@class'
 at [Source: (io.netty.buffer.ByteBufInputStream); line: 1, column: 1695]
```

Comment: Have you tried marking your State class with @Serializable annotation?

Comment: Not the annotation but I tried by implementing Serializable and it seems to work but as soon as I add another type in the object, it starts to complain again. The other object type is beyond my control since it's generated by swagger.

I also remember from other implementations like Lettuce etc that you don't need to actually implement the serializable interface.

Comment: all of the objects that you need to put in to the redis should implement serializable. if the object you are trying to serialize is a 3rd party class, then you should mark it as a transient. But if you still need that 3rd party class and its data, you could try defining a JSONSerializer in your redisconfig. I am not very familiar with kotlin however.

Comment: Can you tell me how to define a JSONSerializer or deserializer in redis config? Java code will do.

Comment: Okay after adding codec the deserialization is broken as described in the original post.

Answer (score 3):

I have created a specific Kotlin JsonJacksonCodec:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.BasicPolymorphicTypeValidator
import org.redisson.codec.JsonJacksonCodec

class JsonJacksonKotlinCodec(objectMapper: ObjectMapper) : JsonJacksonCodec(objectMapper) {

    override fun initTypeInclusion(mapObjectMapper: ObjectMapper) {
        mapObjectMapper.activateDefaultTyping(BasicPolymorphicTypeValidator.builder()
            .allowIfBaseType(Any::class.java)
            .build(), ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.EVERYTHING)
    }
}
```

This Codec overrides all type inclusion logic and includes typing for everything. Data classes, sealed classes and everything works.

To use it:

```
val config = Config()
val codec = JsonJacksonKotlinCodec(ObjectMapper())
codec.objectMapper.registerKotlinModule()
config.codec = codec
config.useSingleServer().address = redisConfig.host
redissonClient = Redisson.create(config).reactive()
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a cleaner way. If `spring-web` jar is on the classpath, Spring Boot will create an `ObjectMapper` with Kotlin support enabled. If not present, simply add `com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin` jar to classpath, and do the following:

Create Kotlin-aware `ObjectMapper`:

```
@Bean
fun objectMapper(): ObjectMapper = jacksonObjectMapper()
```

---

Implement `RedissonAutoConfigurationCustomizer` callback interface:

```
@Bean
fun redisConfigCustomizer(): RedissonAutoConfigurationCustomizer {
    return RedissonAutoConfigurationCustomizer {
        it.codec = JsonJacksonKotlinCodec(objectMapper())
    }
}
```

That's it.